# jquery ajax get to node express, how to get json data?

Tags: jquery, node.js

I'm trying to send the node instance JSON data using an ajax get request clientside as shown below:

```
var parameters = { username: 'test' };
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
      success: function {},
      dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Using firebug, I can see it sends encoded http://server/web_svc?username=test

in my node express method:

```
function svc_method(req, res)
{
   var username = req.body.username;
}
```

req.body.username is undefined. It only works if I post instead of get.

How do I fix this issue? I do have the app.use(express.bodyParser()) line at the top of app.configure().

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `req.query.username` since you want to get a query string param, check the official Express guide: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query

Comment: Query is an object, so you can use `req.query.username` which is the preferred syntax in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your valid observation, indeed req.query.username is the preferred syntax. I made a quick copy-paste from some code :) Edited now.